# unix variable issue while using cron

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have the below code which when run without cron runs fine.

```
sqlplus [user]/[password] @/u/rooney/oracle_sessions/session_count.sql

session_count=`cat session_count.out`

mail -s "Oracle Sessions: $session_count" -c "[email address]" [email address]
```

Sample output:

```
Oracle Sessions: 1126
```

When scheduled with cron, the SQL runs fine and the .out file gets the output (ORACLE environment variables are in place and sql runs fine), but I do not get the out put as above.

```
Oracle Sessions:
```

Not sure what might be missing.

Comment: Did you put the "below code" into a shell script and invoke that from cron, or did you put each line of code on its own line in the crontab file?

Comment: I put it in a shell script and invoked that from cron.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, that means I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: have you tried supplying the full path for session_count.out?

Comment: There was the culprit, can't believe missed that one. Thanks!!